# hadoop streaming Invalid DFS directory name

Tags: php, windows, hadoop

I am still new with `hadoop` and I was trying to get [this example](http://collaboradev.com/2010/12/10/using-hadoop-and-php) to work.

I was able to setup hadoop and run the `wordcount` `mapreduce` example and all is fine. However I am getting a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid DFS directory name` exception when I run a `hadoop` `streaming command` on `windows 7` using `hadoop 2.6.0`

Here is my command:

```
hadoop jar %HADOOP_PREFIX%\share\hadoop\tools\lib\hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.jar -mapper mapper.php -reducer reducer.php -input input/* -output output
```

If I run the command from say folder `d:\hadoop` the error displayed becomes:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid DFS directory name /d:/hadoop
```

The output directory is created before the error is displayed and the job fails.

I tried searching for commands to set the location of the distributed file but I didn't find anything like that.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Input and output paths should be of `hdfs` and not the `local filesytem` path. You are providing input path as `d:/hadoop` which is the `local filesystem`

You will have to find the path in `hdfs` (they usually reside in `/user/<hadoop username>`)

Assuming your `hadoop user` is `Ahmed`, applying following command should give you all the directories and files in `hdfs` home

```
hadoop dfs -ls
```

is equivalent to

```
hadoop dfs -ls /user/Ahmed/
```

So track the hdfs file location and pass it to `-input argument` as (assuming `/user/Ahmed/input` is the path)

```
hadoop jar %HADOOP_PREFIX%\share\hadoop\tools\lib\hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.jar -mapper mapper.php -reducer reducer.php -input /user/Ahmed/input
```

Comment: Thanks Ramesh but I still get the same error. I made sure that the files are added in the hdfs path, I can see them listed when I run "hadoop dfs -ls" and I made sure the input file is set relative to hdfs path. But I still get invalid path and it prints the current directory I am in. I tried giving a wrong path to the input file and it gives a different error, so it does see my input file. I guess that means it is something else?

Comment: can you update your question with all the steps you performed in the comment above? So that I can look at the details. And is `hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.jar` is created by you?

Comment: No I downloaded an already compiled hadoop file for windows and it had all the jar files including wordcount example and streaming jar. I didn't add any extra steps really, I just made sure the input and output path are hdfs path as you pointed out

Comment: @AhmedK. I just wanted to make sure that the current directory is hard coded in the code itself. Thats why I asked you to update the paths you put in the command and the respective errors you get. and also hadoop dfs -ls commands output as well.

Comment: I noticed that when I type "hadoop dfs -ls" cmd it lists the current directory I am running the command from. Is that normal?

Comment: `hadoop dfs -ls` will list whatever path you've create in hdfs. Try to create a directory in root as `hadoop dfs -mkdir /AhmedKTesting` and then apply `hadoop dfs -ls`. Now tell me if current directory get appended to `/AhmedKTesting` as well?

Comment: It creates it in the current directory. I already tried it before but didn't think too much into it

Comment: can you copy paste the output you get when you apply the commands? I need to see them to help you

Comment: the mkdir command doesn't display anything it just creates the folder. Although it prints a deprecated warning if I use "hadoop dfs -mkdir somefile" instead of "hadoop fs -mkdir somefile". As for -ls command it prints found X items and then displays the files/folders in the current directory with permissions and other details

Comment: I need to see exactly whats being printed in the screen. If you are unwilling to share it then I'm afraid I can't help you further

Comment: There really isn't anything to share, as I said one prints nothing and the other lists directories so nothing useful. Anyways I was able to find the issue, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ramesh I noticed that my hdfs commands were running on the current directory not on the hdfs location. So commands like "hdfs dfs -ls /" where listing the directory I am on not what is on the hadoop distributed file system.

It turns out to be an issue with configuration. I had to make sure fs.defaultFS is set correctly in core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml

Comment: Great to hear that you figured it out :)